# Prevent read only mode and issue of saving.

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some code in Visual Basic, which worked perfectly for months. But at some moment this code stopped working:

```
'Save changes to original document
ActiveDocument.Save   ' <- This line causes trouble
'the next line copies the active document
Application.Documents.Add ActiveDocument.FullName
'the next line saves the copy to your location and name
ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveAsPath, wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
```

Instead of saving the original document as it is said in the comment, Word pops up a window and asks to save a document to the folder. It never happened before - document just saved without any additional steps. Probably, it all happens because documents started to open up in read only mode (but I do not remember what mode was in the past, and besides I do not know how to change this mode). I scanned dozens of forums.

**EDIT**

By the way, I also have similar code which saves Excel files, it does it like this:

```
'Save changes to original document
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
'the next line saves the copy to your location and name
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs SaveAsPath
```

The strange thing is that excel files are also opened in read only mode, but still the code works.

**EDIT**

This very, very old [link](http://www.office-forums.com/threads/change-save-location-after-opening-read-only-file.1876088/) is about the same error. I also can register this `Run-Time Error '5155'` if I try to save document.

Comment: How are the documents being opened? In code or manually?  What does it look like if you go open the file manually?  Do you get a prompt about another user with the file open already?

Comment: The documents are being opened through the browser. If I do it manually, then it's ok.

Comment: I do not get such a prompt. However, I investigated it a little bit and found out, that if I use the same code but save the document by another name, then it works.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution (instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Save`):

```
FN = Replace(ActiveDocument.Name, "temp_", "")
FN = "temp_" + FN
'Save changes to original document
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=ActiveDocument.Path + Application.PathSeparator + FN
```

Comment: The idea is to save the document by another name.